# User with nologin or false shell shows no error/action performed

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell

User information from passwd file:

/etc/passwd file info:

mongodb-mms:x:476:472:mongodb-mms:/opt/mongodb/mms:/bin/false

Creating dir and chown for mongodb-mms user:

[root@qaia-opsm home]# pwd
/home

[root@qaia-opsm home]# mkdir testdir1

[root@qaia-opsm home]# chown mongodb-mms:mongodb-mms testdir1

[root@qaia-opsm home]# ls -al

total 52

drwxr-xr-x. 10 root        root         4096 May  5 10:23 .

dr-xr-xr-x. 34 root        root         4096 Apr 28 16:07 ..

drwx------.  4 appeng      appeng       4096 May 30  2014 appeng

drwxr-xr-x   2 mongod      mongod       4096 Feb 13 11:05 data

drwx------.  2 root        root        16384 May 30  2014 lost+found

drwxr-xr-x   3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms  4096 Feb 15 15:08 mongoBackup

drwxr-xr-x   2 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms  4096 May  5 10:23 testdir1

drwx------   4 user1       user1        4096 May  2 16:35 user1

drwx------   4 user2       user2        4096 May  2 12:15 user2

drwx------   4 user3       user3        4096 May  1 17:27 user3

[root@qaia-opsm home]# cd testdir1

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# pwd

/home/testdir1

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# ls

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# su - mongodb-mms touch file1

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# ls -al

total 8

drwxr-xr-x   2 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 4096 May  5 10:23 .

drwxr-xr-x. 10 root        root        4096 May  5 10:23 ..

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# pwd

/home/testdir1

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# su mongodb-mms touch file1

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# ls -al

total 8

drwxr-xr-x   2 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 4096 May  5 10:23 .

drwxr-xr-x. 10 root        root        4096 May  5 10:23 ..

[root@qaia-opsm testdir1]# pwd

/home/testdir1

Comment: I would expect, that you are not able to login with that user. Did you expect, that running  `su  ` will make it possible?

Comment: I cannot login and I am okay not being able to login and there is no password being set on the user mongodb-mms. I am just to su - <username> touch filename in a directory that is owned by mongodb-mms user